# Download txt file issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, response

I'm new in .Net development.
I try to enable downloading txt file:

I use this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                string str = "Test information";
                byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
                System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
                mem.Write(bytes, 0, str.Length);

                Stream outStream = Response.OutputStream;
                Response.ContentType = "application/text/plain";
                Response.AppendHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", " attachment; filename = " + "test.txt");
                mem.WriteTo(outStream);
                outStream.Close();
     }
```

But I get text file with bad first string (problems with encoding) and many other strings with information about current page.

**Update:**
Here is the file I get

```
Bad string
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head><title>
    ASP.NET AJAX Web Services: Web Service Sample Page
</title>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#MainContent_RegisterUser_CreateUserStepContainer_UserName").blur(function (event) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../About.aspx/validateUser",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{'username': '" + $(this).val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: AjaxSucceeded,
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            });
        });
        function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
            if (result.d == "true") {
                $("#LoginSpan").text("РўР°РєРѕР№ РїРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ СѓР¶Рµ СЃСѓС‰РµСЃС‚РІСѓРµС‚");
            }
            else {
                $("#LoginSpan").text("");
            }
        }
        function AjaxFailed(result) {
            alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
        }  
  </script>  
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="BuyingSuccess.aspx?id=19" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE1MjQ5ODA0NjlkGAIFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBSljdGwwMCRIZWFkTG9naW5WaWV3JEhlYWRMb2dpblN0YXR1cyRjdGwwMQUpY3RsMDAkSGVhZExvZ2luVmlldyRIZWFkTG9naW5TdGF0dXMkY3RsMDMFE2N0bDAwJEhlYWRMb2dpblZpZXcPD2QCA2THchHerzY1rr1yLcH18X4YPCuH2pX6++6OU9oOftLDQg==" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>



<script src="/Shop3/WebResource.axd?d=gJqNbXOsVujM8wR8-hfUcLtWhOiTVJCVfh9Lo7jgFFHsWxINU3DVAgCd3VVMHS94GhZGb8YTI_r4HUkshGHWuB2iNiNOHXsKESFMdk577mE1&amp;t=634669639690714017" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgL4/Z3vDgLC0ZzyCk29Agd/VrCau7HXz2AM6rx2j8z5dvoBoXKKKc+infsA" />
</div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    РРЅСЃС‚СЂСѓРєС†РёРё
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">

                                <span class="bold">
                                <span id="HeadLoginView_HeadLoginName">usert</span>
                                </span>
                                <a id="HeadLoginView_HeadLoginStatus" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$HeadLoginView$HeadLoginStatus$ctl00&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Р’С‹Р№С‚Рё</a>

            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/Shop3/WebResource.axd?d=qlxWJrbukMv20w9xY1h0SQe9L8dtSGVTDQ606-0jsJTHpyJh9XQcnnSaKyQTCktjR9G7_qlWhTXAgZB4Ay9LLv-RUiwbYud3LVU-Sm9I6hQ1&amp;t=634669639690714017" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" /></a><div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
    <ul class="level1">
        <li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">РРЅСЃС‚СЂСѓРєС†РёРё</a></li><li><a class="level1" href="About.aspx">Рћ РїСЂРѕРµРєС‚Рµ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">

    <span id="MainContent_Label1">Р’С‹ РєСѓРїРёР»Рё РёРЅСЃС‚СЂСѓРєС†РёСЋ, РїРѕР·РґСЂР°РІР»СЏРµРј!</span>

        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>

<script type='text/javascript'>new Sys.WebForms.Menu({ element: 'NavigationMenu', disappearAfter: 500, orientation: 'horizontal', tabIndex: 0, disabled: false });</script></form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Chars are not bytes.  You need to use the `Encoding` class.

Comment: The content type should probably be just "text/plain"

Comment: Response.ContentType = "text/plain"; didn't help. Please, look at my update - there is a text file I get

Answer (score 1):

Change the ContentType to `application/octet-stream` to ensure the file will be downloaded via all browsers.

e.g change it to this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Charset = "";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.Write(mem.ToArray());
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in the end of Page_load event after outStream.Close(); statement

```
Response.End();
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it is also a good way to use System.Net.WebClient to download strings, bytes or files from a web resource.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
byte[] imageAsBytes = client.DownloadData(uri);
String webSource = client.DownloadString(uri);
client.DownloadFile(uri, "C:\\myfile.txt");
```

It also supports async downloading.

Comment: This should do the encoding automatically.

Comment: The question is about uploading a file to the client.